# Prove or disprove if a quotient map from X to Y with Y Hausdorff, then X is Hausdorff.

Tags: quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

For two open disjoint subsets **U** and **V**, I want to show their pre-images are disjoint open subsets of X or not. But I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hint: let $Y$ be the one-point space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Map $\mathbb R$ with the indiscrete topology to any one point set. The one point set is Hausdorff while $\mathbb R$ under the indiscrete topology is not.

Comment: It might be useful for some readers to point out that there's nothing special about $\mathbb R$ here. Any set with at least two elements would work as well.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Agreed. I upvoted your comment to draw any reader's attention to it.